# Debug ASP.NET k8s services on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there any way to remote debug ASP.NET kubernetes services on GKE?

I tried to search related articles but I only found debugging local kubernetes services or them on AKS (with Visual Studio or VSCode).

**My Environment:**

> **OS(local PC)**: Windows 10
>
> **IDE**: JetBrains Rider / Visual Studio 2022 / VSCode (no matters)
>
> **Language**: .NET 6 (C#)
>
> **Kubernetes**: GKE (Google Cloud)

Answer (score 0):

There is beta version in GKE of attaching remote debugger, Here in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/remote-debugging) to attach the Visual Studio remote debugger to processes on a Compute Engine Virtual Machine running Window,

Try it and let me know if this works.